# Manipulating Taylor expansions and approximations.

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

I am working on this problem:
Consider αy(t + ah) + βy(t + bh)
Find best parameters α,β,a,b that approximates y′(t) at the highest order in h. i.e. Choosing
α, β, a, b what is the highest p below that can be achieved?
y′(t) − [αy(t + ah) + βy(t + bh)] = O(h^p)

I try to use taylor expansion around y(t) and set coefficient of y(t),y'(t),y''(t) to zero to find a solution for the parameters: α=-β,a∝1/h,b∝1/h.
Then consider the orginal eqation αy(t + ah) + βy(t + bh), h vanishes with my solution.I notice something is wrong but I do not understand why.

Comment: I believe you are missing an $h$ in the denominator of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha y(t+ah) + \beta y(t+bh) = \alpha(y(t)+ahy'(t)+a^2h^2/2 y''(t) +\ldots) +$$ $$+\beta (y(t)+bhy'(t)+b^2h^2/2 y''(t) + \ldots).$$
Note that $\alpha + \beta = 0$ (otherwise the values of $y$ won't cancel). We thus get an infinite number of equations on $\alpha, a,b$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha h (a-b) = 1\\
\alpha h^2 (a^2-b^2)/2 = 0\\
\alpha h^3 (a^3-b^3)/6 = 0\\
\ldots
\end{cases}
$$
and we need to find the largest $p$ for which the system of first $p-1$ equations will still have a solution. Indeed, using the first equation to rewrite the others, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha h (a-b) = 1\\
h (a+b)/2 = 0\\
h^2 (a^2+ab+b^2)/6 = 0\\
\ldots
\end{cases}
$$
so in particular $a = -b \not = 0$, however then $a^2 + ab + b^2 = a^2$ is still nonzero, and we can't even do better than $O(h^2)$.